# How to rewrite URL in nginx

Tags: regex, nginx

I'm trying to rewrite the locale part of urls for my website. For example:

[www.site.com/nl-NL](http://www.site.com/nl-NL) to [www.site.com/nl-BE](http://www.site.com/nl-BE)

and

[www.site.com/nl-NL/test/rest](http://www.site.com/nl-NL/test/rest) to [www.site.com/nl-BE/test/rest](http://www.site.com/nl-BE/test/rest)

I got the first one to work but it cuts off the /test/rest part for the second one.

I'm using this in my nginx config:

```
rewrite ^/nl-NL/(.*)$ /nl-BE/$1 permanent;
```

Even all the /nl-BE/... urls are redirected to /nl-BE
Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

My nginx file:

```
server {

  server_name site.com;

  root /var/www/staging/site/front;
  index  index.html index.htm index.php;

  auth_basic "Restricted Content";
  auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;

  gzip on;
  gzip_min_length 128;
  gzip_comp_level 5;
  gzip_proxied any;
  gzip_vary on;
  gzip_types
    application/atom+xml
    application/javascript
    application/json
    application/ld+json
    application/manifest+json
    application/rss+xml
    application/vnd.geo+json
    application/vnd.ms-fontobject
    application/x-font-ttf
    application/x-web-app-manifest+json
    application/xhtml+xml
    application/xml
    font/opentype
    image/bmp
    image/svg+xml
    image/x-icon
    text/cache-manifest
    text/css
    text/plain
    text/vcard
    text/vnd.rim.location.xloc
    text/vtt
    text/x-component
    text/x-cross-domain-policy;

  set $skip_cache 1;

  location / {
    expires 1h;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" always;
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";

    add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;
    add_header X-Developer "Name";

    if ($request_uri ~* ".(ico|woff|woff2|css|js|svg|gif|jpe?g|png)$") {
      expires 100d;
      access_log off;
      add_header Pragma public;
      add_header Cache-Control "public";
      break;
    }

    if ($request_uri ~* ".(js)$") {
      expires 7d;
    }

    proxy_redirect                      off;
    proxy_set_header Host               $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
    proxy_ignore_headers        Cache-Control;
    proxy_http_version          1.1;
    proxy_read_timeout          1m;
    proxy_connect_timeout       1m;
    proxy_pass                  http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    proxy_hide_header X-Powered-By;
  }
location /forms {
    set $skip_cache 1;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /forms.php?$query_string;
  }

  location /geoip {
    set $skip_cache 1;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /geoip.php?$query_string;
  }

  location /cacheclear.php {
    set $skip_cache 1;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /cacheclear.php?$query_string;
  }

  location /sitemap.xml {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /sitemap.php?$query_string;
  }



    location ~ .php$ {

    fastcgi_cache_bypass $skip_cache;
    fastcgi_no_cache $skip_cache;

    fastcgi_cache php_cache;
    fastcgi_cache_valid 200 999999999m;
    fastcgi_cache_methods GET;

            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
            fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
            #Avoid sending the security headers twice
            fastcgi_param modHeadersAvailable true;
            fastcgi_param front_controller_active true;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
            fastcgi_request_buffering off;
    }

  location /nl-NL {
    rewrite ^/nl-NL$ /nl-BE permanent;
  }

listen 80;
}
```

Comment: At the first glance it doesn't seem like there is a mistake in this line, can I see the rest of the configuration?

Comment: It's a pretty big file but i just added it

Comment: Here's one idea, not sure if it's going to work. `location ~ ^/nl-NL(?<local_path>/.*) {
    rewrite ^/nl-NL/.*$ /nl-BE$local_path permanent;
  }`

Comment: How are you testing this? Use `curl -I` to check the response from Nginx as browsers can give confusing results. The `rewrite` at the top of your question is fine. The `rewrite` in the configuration you posted is obviously wrong.

Comment: @FonsVC Remove that `location /nl-NL { ... }` block and add `rewrite ^/nl-NL(/?.*)$ /nl-BE$1 permanent;` instead.